# Filter out certain posts in Google+

Tags: google-plus

How can I filter out certain posts from showing up in my Google+ feed?

For example, if I don't want to see more and more posts related to "disney AND lucasfilm", is there any way that I can add such filter and do something like a "mute" or "mark as read" that one would do in Gmail filters?

What would be the equivalent in Google+?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Chrome extension called G+ Hashtags which will allow you to filter out things like #caturday.  It's not much help if people aren't tagging consistently, and it doesn't sync across browsers via Chrome sync.  Not perfect, but it has helped me clean up my stream a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another Google+ solution is to select which circles are posting the most about the topic you don't want to see, and limit the amount of posts you see from that circle.

From the `Home` tab, select a circle at the top and then move the slider to meet your needs.

[image]